# Android app downloaded from PlayStore still using testing mode for in-app purchase

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I've implemented in-app purchases and submitted my app to PlayStore.
It's all approved.

Then I've downloaded my app from the PlayStore. When I opened the subscription page and tried to subscribe and **it's still using testing mode**... ???

Is it just my device (my account that is used for testing mode) or is it some fundamental mistake? I don't think they would have approved it if something was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

It's normal, because you are a licensed tester and as such, you are in testing mode, even on your published app:

> When your In-app Billing implementation is ready, you can test purchasing of your in-app SKUs in two ways:
>
> - **Test purchases**, which let your selected license-test users purchase your in-app products without any resulting charges to the user. **Test purchases can be used in alpha/beta releases or in published apps**.
> - **Real purchases**, which ...

source: [Testing In-app Purchases](http://android-doc.github.io/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html#testing-purchases)

And you are a licensed tester because you've added yourself to the list of the licensed testers OR because you are the publisher of the app, [as stated here](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6062777?hl=en):

> Your own publishing account is always considered a licensed tester.

Comment: Thank you! That's interesting. I just think it would be nice to be able to delete my account as a tester account, then test a real purchase, and then put it back in testing mode. By the way, in AppStore, that moment looks less confusing.

Comment: Yes, the App Store is way better for this since you have a special account for testing.

Comment: So what are my options? Should I create another google account? I mean ...@gmail.com. Or is it still going to be considered as testing because it belongs to the same person?

Comment: It's a really good question and I'm afraid I don't have the answer. Creating a new Play Store account should obviously work, but I don't know if there is any other way.